# CNN Error Runtime Error while Following Tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torchvision

I'm following [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/shadabhussain/cifar-10-cnn-using-pytorch/notebook) tutorial for trying to implement CNN with PyTorch. I had gotten past every step so far but I am now stuck on the part "Training and Validating Datasets." I had been getting the error below:

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

So far, this is my code:

```
# Import whatever libraries/modules you need

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
import torch
import torchvision
import tarfile
from torchvision.datasets.utils import download_url
from torch.utils.data import random_split
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
from torchvision.utils import make_grid

# Dowload the dataset
dataset_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-imageclas/cifar10.tgz"
download_url(dataset_url, '.')

# # Extract from archive to data/cifar10, containing training set and test set
# with tarfile.open('./cifar10.tgz', 'r:gz') as tar:
#     tar.extractall(path='./data')

# Verify using os.listdir
data_dir = './data/cifar10'

print(os.listdir(data_dir))
classes = os.listdir(data_dir + "/train")
print(classes)

# Load Data as PyTorch Tensors
dataset = ImageFolder(data_dir+'/train', transform=ToTensor())

#Display image using matplotlib but change the tensor dimensions to (32, 32, 3)
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = '#ffffff'

def show_example(img, label):
    print('Label: ', dataset.classes[label], "("+str(label)+")")
    plt.imshow(img.permute(1, 2, 0))
    plt.show()

show_example(*dataset[0])
show_example(*dataset[1099])

# Training
random_seed = 42
torch.manual_seed(random_seed);
val_size = 5000
train_size = len(dataset) - val_size


train_ds, val_ds = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])
len(train_ds), len(val_ds)

batch_size=128
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
val_dl = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size*2, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)

# Look at batches of images from the dataset using the make grid method
# Gets a random batch each time since the sampler shuffles the indices before creating batches

def show_batch(dl):
    for images, labels in dl:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
        ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.imshow(make_grid(images, nrow=16).permute(1, 2, 0))
        break
show_batch(train_dl)
```

This error has started after including the "#Training" section as seen below. I am running this on Windows 11 with PyCharm on Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   #your code
```